# Blender Python - how to call a class or function?

Tags: python

So I made a tiny UI with a button that calls a class.

```
row = layout.row(align=True)
row.operator("object.sal_locator", text="Locator", icon="CON_TRACKTO")
```

Then on that class during it's execute I wanted to run another class or function (in this case a modal operator) but I have been having issues calling that class

```
class SAL_Locator(bpy.types.Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    bl_idname = "object.sal_locator"
    bl_label = "Connecting Lines"

    def execute(self, context):
        SAL_Locator_Mirror() #??????????
```

The class being called.

```
class SAL_Locator_Mirror(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.sal_locator_mirror"
    bl_label = "Locator Mirror Modal Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        pass
    def modal(self, context, event):
        pass
```

What is the correct syntax to make a class call or a function call inside blender?

Because I want to make a call of a modal operator I am forced to call a class and I cant use a function right?

Comment: Doesn't call a class, calls the operator `bpy.ops.object.sal_locator()` defined by registering the class.   _"Because I want to make a call of a modal operator I am forced to call a class and I cant use a function right?"_  wrong.

Comment: The directly call class need to implement magic method `__call__` so you can call that class like `class_obj()`. But that's not how Blender call your operator and `bpy.types.Operator` doesn't implement `__call__` at all.